# event.params.userId is undefined in cloud function firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have not being able to readthe userId of the person who has written to the real time database, The code is much bigger but here is a simplified version of it. When I add something to the data base I get user id is undefined.

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var waiting= "waiting";



exports.logUserId= 
functions.database.ref('/resquests/{userId}').onCreate(event => {

     var user = event.params.userId;
     console.log("user id "+event.params.userId)


});
```

Comment: What happens if you log the value of just `event.params`?

Comment: Also, what version of the firebase-functions module are you using, and have you tried updating it to the latest?

Comment: When I log just event.params I get this: { userId: undefined }. And how do I go about updating it to the latest?

Comment: `cd functions` `npm install firebase-functions@latest`

Comment: @FranTardencilla try and use `onWrite()` instead of `onCreate()` and tell me if it works

Comment: Initially the function was triggered by onWrite() but then I realized that was not what I wanted so I changed it to onCreate(), however I could not get the userId in ether case. And bthw  I am using the google console online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my function locally on my pc then deployed it using the firebase commands from the cmd on my computer, originally the function was created to respond to onWrite() events and I had not included the {userId} part on my reference however later on I realized that I could edit the function from the Google console online, so all subsequent changes I made were done using the online console.

Somehow the main updates on the code such as adding the {userId} reference or changing the trigger event were not taking effect when made from the online console, so I deployed the updated function from the cmd on my pc and now it all works like a charm :)